# sql error 1064 when i change inner join to left join

Tags: mysql, sql

i write sql

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as count,g.name
FROM
    test_scale g
        INNER JOIN
    test_user_scale_result a
        INNER JOIN
    en_org_user_department b
        INNER JOIN
    en_org_department d
        INNER JOIN
    test_scale_type e ON a.user_id = b.user_id
        AND g.id = a.scale_id
        AND b.department_id = d.id
        AND d.position LIKE CONCAT((SELECT 
                    position
                FROM
                    en_org_department
                WHERE
                    id = 8),
            '%')
        AND e.id = g.scale_type_id
        and b.status = 1
        and g.scale_type_id IN (1 , 9)
        and a.create_time BETWEEN '2015-01-07 18:09:45' and '2015-11-09 18:09:45'
        group by a.scale_id;
```

i run correctly.
but when i change inner to left,like

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as count,g.name
FROM
    test_scale g
        left JOIN
    test_user_scale_result a
        left JOIN
    en_org_user_department b
        left JOIN
    en_org_department d
        left JOIN
    test_scale_type e ON a.user_id = b.user_id
        AND g.id = a.scale_id
        AND b.department_id = d.id
        AND d.position LIKE CONCAT((SELECT 
                    position
                FROM
                    en_org_department
                WHERE
                    id = 8),
            '%')
        AND e.id = g.scale_type_id
        and b.status = 1
        and g.scale_type_id IN (1 , 9)
        and a.create_time BETWEEN '2015-01-07 18:09:45' and '2015-11-09 18:09:45'
        group by a.scale_id;
```

> it error 20:37:15 SELECT      * FROM  test_user_scale_result a
>   left JOIN     en_org_user_department b         left JOIN
>   en_org_department d         left JOIN     test_scale_type e       left
>   JOIN     test_scale g    ON a.user_id = b.user_id         AND g.id =
>   a.scale_id         AND b.department_id = d.id         AND d.position
>   LIKE CONCAT((SELECT                      position                 FROM
>   en_org_department                 WHERE                     id = 8),
>   '%')         AND e.id = g.scale_type_id         and b.status = 1
>   and g.scale_type_id IN (1 , 9)         and a.create_time BETWEEN
>   '2015-01-07 18:09:45' and '2015-11-09 18:09:45'   Error Code: 1064. You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line
>   26    0.0060 sec

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: BTW, syntax error in both queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the join conditions in the proper `ON` clauses, not all together in one final `ON`, like this:

```
SELECT      count(*) as count,
            g.name
FROM        test_scale g
LEFT JOIN   test_user_scale_result a
        ON  g.id = a.scale_id
        AND a.create_time BETWEEN '2015-01-07 18:09:45' and '2015-11-09 18:09:45'
LEFT JOIN   en_org_user_department b
        ON  a.user_id = b.user_id
        AND b.status = 1
LEFT JOIN   en_org_department d
        ON  b.department_id = d.id
        AND d.position LIKE CONCAT(
                (SELECT position
                FROM    en_org_department
                WHERE   id = 8),
                '%')
LEFT JOIN   test_scale_type e
        ON  e.id = g.scale_type_id
WHERE       g.scale_type_id IN (1, 9)
GROUP BY    g.name;
```

The condition on the `g.scale_type_id` should appear in the `WHERE` clause, unless you really want to have other records included.

Note also, that it is advised to group by g.name, since that is the column you `SELECT` for having the related count. In Standard `SQL` it is mandatory to `GROUP BY` the non-aggregated columns that you have in your `SELECT` list.

Comment: i change left join,but the results is not correct,i wonder there is redundant data

Answer (score 1):

I think `left join` requires an `on` clause immediately following the join.  Really, you should always be doing this anyway:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as count,g.name
FROM
    test_scale g left JOIN
    test_user_scale_result a
    ON g.id = a.scale_id AND a.create_time BETWEEN '2015-01-07 18:09:45' and '2015-11-09 18:09:45' left JOIN
    en_org_user_department b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND b.status = 1 left JOIN
    en_org_department d
    ON b.department_id = d.id AND
       d.position LIKE CONCAT((SELECT position FROM en_org_department WHERE id = 8),
                              '%') left JOIN
    test_scale_type e
    ON e.id = g.scale_type_id
WHERE g.scale_type_id IN (1 , 9)
group by a.scale_id;
```

Note:

- I'm pretty sure the conditions on the particular tables need to go in the `ON` clause where that table first appears.  I don't think the `left join` will work if all of them are stuffed in the final `on` clause.
- The conditions on the first table should be in a `where` clause.  Otherwise, you'll get strange results.
- Here are some simple rules when using joins.  (1) Always have an `ON` clause follow every `JOIN`, except for a `CROSS JOIN`.  (2) Never use commas in the `FROM` clause (you aren't doing this, but I always throw this in).